# Finding if the records associated with a customer id is all unique

Tags: mysql, sql, database, spreadsheet

I have a table with two columns, first column is the customer id and second column is the item id (a unique id associated with all the items present in the store). Our dataset is such that if the customer at a certain day buy five items then there will be five rows associated with same customer id for five items but if at the some other day the same customer buy 4 items then we will again have 4 rows for that same customer id.

the image indicates that customer with id 5232 buys 6 different items at a certain day, and customer with id 6543 buys 4 different items and customer with id 5232 again at some other day buys 4 more items but two of the items are of same id.

[image]

What i want is "to verify that all the items bought by a certain customer at a particular day is all different or not". As the dataset is pretty huge so i am looking for some sql query which can do so.

The output should be:

- For customer id 5232 at first day it should return true (all the item ids are different)
- For customer id 6543 it should also return true.
- For customer id 5232 at different day it should return false. (two items have same id 342)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Where is the date field? So first `342` is ok, but you buy again other day and isnt?

Comment: There is no date field. It is like all the items bought by a certain customer at certain day will be all continuous and if the customer comes and buy items again after some customer id then it is considered as a different day. Like first 6 rows with 5232 are considered same day and with a discontinuity 5232 comes again so it is considered different day. My requirement is to find that at a certain day items bought by a customer is all different.

Comment: can you show us how would looks that output? multiple rows for customer? show item_id ?

Comment: and you should have one id column or date column, otherwise you cant tell when the  item is buy again.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Output should be a column. For a customer at a certain day if all the items bought are different then the value in the column should be true otherwise false. Like for above table output should be column of three entries:
--First entry is for 5232 and it should return true. (all the 6 items are different)
--Second entry is for 6543 and it should also be true.
-- Third entry also be true (all 4 items bought are unique)  for 5232 (at some other day)

Comment: as I told you, then you need to add a date column. And please read the links.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t.CustomerId
    ,t.Date
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT t.ItemId) as NumOfItems
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT t2.ItemId) as NumOfRepeatedItems
    ,CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.ItemId) > 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END as UniquePurchases
FROM
    Table t
    LEFT JOIN Table t2
    ON t.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId
    AND t.ItemId = t2.ItemId
    AND t.Date > t2.Date
GROUP BY
    t.CustomerId
    ,t.Date
```

You can use a `LEFT SELF JOIN` back to itself to see if that same customer purchased the same item on a previous date.

I am assuming of course that you have the ability of adding a date column into the query as you have discussed date in your post.  It would be vital to have some way of grouping the purchases by date or common id.

Comment: there is no `date` column, OP say changing `customer_id` mean different date :/

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza while after re-reading I see what you are saying I have never seen a transaction system that wouldn't either have a date for the order and/or Order Id so while I would guess the OP omitted it I would think it is there as well.  The only other way would to create a common grouping id by generating a row number and determining gaps then use that grouping id to as a common id